# I cannot move files to the trash in ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, trash

I have a HDD with a ext4 partition reserved just for files, and when I try to put some file in the trash, It will show me the error:

[image]

I already check for this, and try [image]

But when I did this. It will appear the following message error while I try to mount the partition:
[image]

I have other disk partition that contain windows and there I don't get the problem neither in my ubuntu partition. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems sda8 is not formatted or damaged. You can format a drive (create basic filesystem structures) by running

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda8
```

If it's damaged you can try to recover important files from that partition (if any) and then format it hopeing that this will fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. The partition is not damaged because when I remove the code: "uid = 1000" from the disk option  it turns back to the normal. But I still don't have the option to put the files on the trash, it only allows delete them.